# Join nested array and output comma-separated list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to print a comma-separated list of items in an array.

Example:

```
[
{value: 1, text: 'one},
{value: 2, text: 'two},
{value: 3, text: 'three},
{value: 4, text: 'four},
]
```

I thought about solving this with Array.join (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) - but this is not working with arrays containing more information, as the output is `[object Object]`.

How can I "pick" the value and join the value so I'm getting `one, two, three, four` as output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to `map` over your array to grab the `text` prop out of it and *then* apply the desired `join`.

```js
const arr = [
  {value: 1, text: 'one'},
  {value: 2, text: 'two'},
  {value: 3, text: 'three'},
  {value: 4, text: 'four'}
];

const output = arr.map(el => el.text).join(', ');

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
{{array.map(x =>  x.text).join(', ')}}
```